# Matlab : Array formatting

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

Okay, so I have two Variables - Events `12x1`, type `12x1`. which look like follow;

```
Events =
   13.0850
   15.1860
   20.1470
   24.3080
   27.3030
   29.4180
   33.2930
   36.3710
   38.7080
   42.4300
   44.6670
   46.9640

type = 
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
```

I want to write the following to a file(.txt) which has header as the variable names with their values beneath them. Or could i just concatenate the cell array to the numeric double array and write to a file?

Comment: And please can someone tell me how to me how to form an array which looks like A =[ 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2] without  using loops pleasee

Comment: That's a different question. Yo can post that as a new a question. But make sure you correctly specify the problem. An example array doesn't tell the rule by which you want to create those arrays. Is it two repeated numbers? Or not always two? Are the numbers always consecutive? ...?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure! Could you help me out with this question though :/

Comment: Show some code for this. There are plenty docs on how to write to files with Matlab

Comment: sorry I don't really understand what you want. You wish to print a 2x12 cell array with the 1st row being the `type` and the 2nd row being the `Events`? If so, consult the docs as @Dan mentioned there are many examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in recent releases of MATLAB, the simplest way is to bring the variables together into a table, then write out the table.

```
>> myevents = [1;2;3]
myevents =
     1
     2
     3
>> mytypes = {'control';'control';'control'}
mytypes = 
    'control'
    'control'
    'control'
>> t = table(myevents, mytypes)
t = 
    myevents     mytypes 
    ________    _________
    1           'control'
    2           'control'
    3           'control'
>> writetable(t,'myfile.csv')
>> type('myfile.csv') % Display contents of the file just created

myevents,mytypes
1,control
2,control
3,control
```

`table` was introduced in R2013b. Prior to that release, the simplest way is to use the lower-level functions such as `fprintf` to write the file directly.

---

**Edit**: If you have a version older than R2013b, you can use something like the following:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv','w');
for i = 1:numel(myevents)
    fprintf(fid, '%f,%s\n', myevents(i), mytypes{i});
end
fclose(fid);

>> type('myfile.csv')

myevents,mytypes
1.000000,control
2.000000,control
3.000000,control
```

Use the format specifiers (such as `%f`, `%s`) to specify the output format for numbers. See `doc fprintf` to find details of them.

Comment: i have r2011b, could please show me how to do it with fprintf? i used fprintf(fid,'%f %f %c\n',Events,position,type);.. but it tells me that fprintf cant be used for cell